# strtotime not adding date correctly

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I'm trying to add a calculated number of days to today's date.  I am creating a string '+93 days' for strtodate using a calculation to get the 93.  When i type the string out it in strtotime, I get the correct date.  When I use the calculation to build a string (see below), I get a drastically wrong date.  Is there a better way to format my string or another option?

```
  function debtPayoffDate($mPay, $balance, $irr) {
        $days = 365/12*(log($mPay) - log($mPay-$balance*$irr/12))/log(1+$irr/12);
        $days = round($days, 0);
        $daysString = "'+" . $days . " days'";
        echo $daysString;
        $payoffDate = date("m/d/y", strtotime($dayString));
        echo $payoffDate;
    }
    debtPayoffDate($mPay, $balance, $irr);
```

The output I get for this is '+93 days'12/31/69, rather than the correct result which is '+93 days'11/16/16

Comment: try         $daysString = "+" . $days . " days";

Answer (score 1):

1. Wrong formatting in `$daysString`, ditch the single quotes.
2. wrong variable name in `strtotime($dayString)`, it should be`$daysString`